# Transferring data from service.ts to component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am really stuck in this problem, hopefully I can get some help here.

Basically, I am doing a simple get http request in http.service and then transferring the json object to the filter.service. After that I want to carry the output array into component. But I get an empty error.

**http.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

constructor(private http : Http) { }

getData() {
return this.http.get('https://angular2-49133.firebaseio.com/catalog.json')
       .map((response : Response) => response.json());
}

}
```

**filtering.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

@Injectable()
export class FilterService {
public dataArr = [];
constructor(private httpService : HttpService) { }

setData() {
this.httpService.getData()
  .subscribe((data) => 
      {
        const resultArr = [];
        for(let key in data) {
          resultArr.push(data[key]);
        }
       this.dataArr = resultArr; //console.log(resultArr) works in component.
      }
  )
}

getData() {
return this.dataArr;
}

}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FilterService } from '../../filter.service';

@Component({
selector: 'ubi-item-section',
templateUrl: './item-section.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./item-section.component.css']
})
export class ItemSectionComponent implements OnInit{
items = [];
filter;
constructor(private filterService : FilterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.filterService.setData();
this.items = this.filterService.getData()

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of returning promise from `setData` function as soon as `this.dataArr` object gets filled up.

**Code**

```
setData() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    this.httpService.getData()
      .subscribe((data) => 
         {
            const resultArr = [];
            for(let key in data) {
              resultArr.push(data[key]);
            }
            this.dataArr = resultArr;
            resolve(this.dataArr); //resolve function will complete promise
         }
      );
   }
}
```

You should be waiting till `setData` method ajax to be completed by putting `then` call on promise.

```
this.filterService.setData().then(
   () => this.items = this.filterService.getData()
);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked perfect. I also got to learn about promises. I just had to put extra parenthesis for promise function. Can you also tell me why it didnt' work without promise?

Comment: Because as soon as you do `.subscribe` over that observable it doesn't allow to re-emit data.. That's why custom Promise would be helpful in this situation...

Answer (score 0):

you are using an asynchronous function `setData` so you have to wait 
until until the observable resolves:

try this

**filtering.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

@Injectable()
export class FilterService {
public dataArr = [];
constructor(private httpService : HttpService) { }

getData() {
return this.httpService.getData()
  .map((data) => 
      {
        const resultArr = [];
        for(let key in data) {
          resultArr.push(data[key]);
        }
       return resultArr; //console.log(resultArr) works in component.
      }
  )
}


}
```

**component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FilterService } from '../../filter.service';

@Component({
selector: 'ubi-item-section',
templateUrl: './item-section.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./item-section.component.css']
})
export class ItemSectionComponent implements OnInit{
items = [];
filter;
constructor(private filterService : FilterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.filterService.getData().subscribe((items)=>{
      this.items = items;
   });
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in http.service, observable is returned after calling get and map methods.

Comment: there's no problem with that you can call `map` method many times if you want.